# Why does applying the star operator to the values in dict_items within a comprehension wrap each value in a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterable-unpacking

I ran the following in the `python3` interpreter:

```py
>>> d = dict( a=1, b=2 )
>>> [v for k,*v in d.items()]
[[1], [2]]
```

Why does using the star operator in this context cause each value to get wrapped in a `list`?

Comment: I failed to visually parse this correctly. The individual `int`s aren't magically getting wrapped in a `list`. Each key-value pair in `d.items()` is itself a sequence that is assigned to `k,*v` (e.g. `k,*v = 'a', 1`).